# Does compiler always use built-in type template params to decorate function name

Tags: c++, templates

When generating the function name, will the compiler always add template params into that name to make sure that the function name is unique? I am especially interested in the case where the template param is a built in type. Here is an example with some pseudocode:

```
template class<int32_t Size>
class Foo
{
public:
    ...

    // Signature does not depend on size
    void doSomething()
    {
        m_bar.doWork(Size);
    }
    
    // Some functions that depend on the value of Size
    ...

private:
    // Bar does not depend on Size
    Bar m_bar;

    // Some members that depend on the value of Size
    ...
};
```

Will instantiating the class above for two different values of `Size` result in two unique names for `doSomething`?

Comment: "Will instantiating the class above for two different values of Size result in two unique names for doSomething?" Name decoration ("mangling") was invented precisely for this to happen.

Comment: "Signature does not depend on size" but the doSomething function itself does depend on Size. If the compiler had generated the same symbol for different Size values, how would it know what value to use for Size in doSomething?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Possibly. Not necessarily.

The C++ standard does not mandate how implementations do their thing. While it has certain minor facilities that at least *hint* at the use of a thing called "name mangling", it certainly isn't necessary. You don't need a "linker", let alone a linker which works based on "symbol names", to make a standard-compliant C++ compiler.

What the C++ standard *does* mandate is that `Foo<4>::doSomething()` invokes `Bar::doWork()` with the argument `4`, and that `Foo<2>::doSomething()` invokes `Bar::doWork()` with the argument `2`. So it would not be okay for a compiler to confuse the two.

Comment: It's hard to think of a way to have 2 implementations of doSomething w/o having two different names. Unless you mean that it is possible to have no names at all, just absolute locations.

Comment: @YaroslavFyodorov By "name" I guess you mean "a string of characters used to uniquely identify a function"? Well, the other options would be "unique identifiers which are not strings of characters".

Comment: I would say absolute location is kind of a name, just not very convenient

Comment: @YaroslavFyodorov Unless the addresses of the functions are taken I think it also would be ok for the implementation to actually just create one function and to provide `size` as part of the function call. The whole program would have to be known in that case of course.

Comment: @YaroslavFyodorov I'm not sure I follow your point. It sounds like you're saying "you can't uniquely identify things unless you can uniquely identify them", but that's tautological.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Well, when I compile with -O3, g++ just inlines the hell out of everything and doesn't create even one function ))

Comment: @Sneftel Ok, you win. Anyway, my guess is OP was actually asking whether there will be two implementations, not names per se

Comment: @TedLyngmo On a more serious note: I don't think it would be ok, especially as the template param is on the class, not on the function. So, you have two (or more) copies of all the functions of the class, not just that one and it's a relatively complicated analysis to see what use is done of this template param - it can be used in expressions that require a constant (array size?)

Comment: @YaroslavFyodorov Yes, but given that the compiler would manage to figure that out I don't there is anything preventing an implementation to reuse the same function body. The `size` template parameter, if it's actually used in the function, could be passed in a register etc.

Comment: Either way, it's very compiler-specific. You can also see this in the boost libraries, which has functions to pretty-print type names which only work on supported compilers, and other libraries such as magicenum which also use name trickery to do their thing.

Regardless, for the commonly used compilers that use mangled strings, two distinct functions/types will always yield two distinct strings. Also, keep in mind that if the compiler determines that two distinct functions are the same, it can just give two names to the compiled function, so callers don't need to know that.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You must have two implementations of `doSomething` because they pass different params to `doWork`

This is how it looks with g++ on Mac with main that instantiates Foo with two different params:

```
#include <cstdint>

class Bar {
  public:
  int doWork(int32_t size) { return (int)size; } 
};

template <int32_t Size> class Foo 
{
  private:
  // Bar does not depend on Size
  Bar m_bar;

  public:

  // Signature does not depend on size
  void doSomething()
  {
    m_bar.doWork(Size);
  }
 };

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    Foo<5>().doSomething();
    Foo<7>().doSomething();
    return 0;
}
```

Here part of the output of `nm a.out` which lists all the defined symbols - one function for `Foo<5>` and one for `Foo<7>`

```
...
0000000100003f14 T __ZN3FooILi5EE11doSomethingEv
0000000100003f3c T __ZN3FooILi7EE11doSomethingEv
...
```

Answer (score 1):

A possible alternative implementation to do this without name mangling would be to only make one function and store the template parameter in the virtual table.

Effectively making the compiler see something like this.

```
doSomething() {
  mBar.doWork(vtab.Size);
}
```

OK, I don't know any compiler that does this and as @TedLyngmo commented, his compiler inlined everything, which is definitely a good thing.